# When dealing with sequences, should we teach students to start at 0 or 1?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

The reason I prefer starting at 0 is due to a computer science background and also, I think it helps to start at 0 because there are certain reasons that demand it (in particular, combinatorics) and I think having exposure to starting at 0 is 'healthier' in the long run?

Teaching both starting at 0 or 1 is probably cause for confusion for a lot of students and they usually do not have the discernment to decide which to start at.

Any advice on the issue?

Comment: I go with the author of the textbook I use, and I discuss this issue with the students.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/163/

Comment: Might be useful: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/213/9907, https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/5023/9907

Comment: What number makes more sense as the first term in a sequence? Which applications are they seeing these sequences used for? (because those who aren't up to handling a switch between start points, are not going to be aiming at pure maths pathways).

Comment: I would make a stronger claim: if the students struggle to understand that it does not matter whether to start indexing at 0 or 1, then you cannot teach them anything substantial about sequences anyway.

Comment: What age are we talking about?  Little kids learn to count at 1 and aren't ready to learn to count from 0.

Comment: @Nij - those who aren't up to handling a switch aren't going to be successful programmers in industry either.

Comment: @AmyB, "At first there was nothing..."

Comment: @RustyCore little kids in the US learn to count from their parents, books, and sesame street.  All of them start with 1.  Suddenly switching to 0 will confuse them.  If the OP is talking about older kids then it is a different discussion. The OP hasn't specified an age.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, yep, some languages index arrays starting from 0 (e.g. Python) and others start from 1 (e.g. Julia).